# Seeking SVG symbol library for QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, software-recommendations, svg

I am currently using default simple symbol capabilities or dingbats fonts for point objects.

Is there maybe a SVG symbol library for QGIS that is a bit more extensive than that which is included?

I've found this site http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com which has some icons but its not what im looking for. These are actually more suitable for google maps.

Comment: Why not just load a saved image from file onto your composer. For instance i did not like the standard north arrows so saved an image and loaded it on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll find some symbols and the way to install them on http://ssrebelious.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/qgis-symbology-set/:

> 1. Use QGIS 1.7 or higher.
> 2. Go to Settings->Style manager.
> 3. Hit “Import” button.
> 4. Provide path to the “symbology-ng-style-eng.xml” file in this archive.
> 5. Pick up needed symbols or choose all of them and hit “Import” button.

Comment: Thank you, i ll give it a shot. What bothers me with the link i posted is, that symbol have arrows which point down, which means that the symbol isn't as useful if you want to place it centered on a feature.

Comment: For me the majority of symbols just have "?" in them... using QGIS Wein 2.8.1

Answer (score 9):

Tho it's not a set of Symbols, in [the noun project](http://thenounproject.com/) you can download many SVG files (under [creative commons licence](http://creativecommons.org)) that can easily used to create composed symbols in QGIS.

Answer (score 6):

Not QGIS-specific, but [Maki](http://mapbox.com/maki/) is a map-specific icon set in SVG from MapBox.

Comment: It can be installed using the QGIS Resource Sharing plugin

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a library but it's a very good site that has a ton of free icons (and some packs) in several formats including the all-important svg. You aren't likely to find useful bundled icons here but it is great for plugging the gaps in the very basic QGIS svg symbol set. It also has a handy icon basket so you can mark the ones you want as you go, then downloaded them all in a single zip file:

https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/icon/

Answer (score 0):

Not restricted to QGIS, here is another one from where I obtain or derive icons for e.g. cartography or GUI design:

https://openclipart.org/https://openclipart.org/

Everything is licenced under the CC0 1.0 Universal (CC0 1.0)
Public Domain Dedication License: https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/