# How to add my own symbols to the single-marker or svg-marker selection list?

Tags: qgis

I was creating an arrow for a line layer. So I was adding the triangle as a single marker to the line. So far so good. But when I would like to create my own single-marker symbol or svg marker how can I add these own symbols to QGIS? 
Where have these own symbols to be stored? So that they are added to the single marker or svg marker selection list?

I could not found the folder by searching for .svg files? ;( 
What's the approach to put my own single marker or svg marker to the selection list?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

From the SVG marker dialog you can select a different SVG file. Also, its here you will see where the default file is stored.

[image: SVG dialog]

you might wanna check my post from a few days about additional libraries of SVG symbols:

[Is there a SVG symbol library for qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/is-there-a-svg-symbol-library-for-qgis)

Comment: Thank your for answer! It helped me a lot. The yellow marked path is not appearing in my symbol properties window ;( Actually, I am also looking where the font-marker symbols are stored? I have not found these until now. Do you know where the single-marker (circle, rectangles usw.) symbols are stored? There is no path indicated when selecting the single-marker symbol and also no path indication field. Thank's in advance for any information. Best regards phil

Comment: Those are not actually stored in  a file, i think the options there are simply hardcoded, they aren't read from a file.

Answer (score 7):

Go Settings -> Options -> Rendering: there will be "SVG paths" at the bottom. Click "Add" button to add new path. (NB: In newer QGIS versions Settings -> Options -> System and "SVG paths" is at the top)

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I have already added my own folder :)

Comment: @philmyer this answer is the implemented method of adding one's own SVG symbols.  Consider marking it as the accepted answer. The other symbols you are referring to, I believe, are drawn on-demand by the Qt GUI toolkit, and as such, aren't located in the file system.

Comment: BTW: [starting here in the source code](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/core/symbology-ng/qgsmarkersymbollayerv2.cpp#L240) are the two methods where the simple markers are 'prepared' before being rendered. Not sure how easy it would be to add more.

Comment: ...thank's for the information. But I will do it by creating my own arrowhead as a SVG-file (see the comment at the bottom).

Comment: I noticed that in QGIS 2.2 that the "SVG Paths" location is now in Settings -> Otions -> System.

Answer (score 0):

The default directory folders (categorized by type) for the the svg symbols are located on my computer in C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\svg. It has been my experience that if I create a new svg symbol, save it to any of these directories while I have a project open, I have to restart the project (QGIS) before it will be visible and selectable in the symbol properties dialog box.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Do you also know where the single-maker symbols (circles, rectangles usw) are stored? I could not found them until now ;( Thank's in advance for any advice, Best regards, phil

Comment: It is my understanding these symbols are "simple" markers and are rendered in a manner (best answer) noted in the previous answer comments provided by dakarto above. That is not to say that you couldn't prepare your own interpretation of these symbols in svg format using a program like inkscape and save them to a directory of your choosing.

Comment: ... thanks for the information. I think the easiest way will be to create my own arrowhead in Adobe Illustrator and save it as svg. This arrowhead.svg can be used as a my own svg-marker. Creating my own arrow by combining two symbol layers: A single line (symbol layer1) and the own arrowhead.svg (symbol layer2). That’s it ☺