# Can you print cross-hatch area fills like they appear on screen?

Tags: qgis, cartography, symbology, scale

I'm trying to use a cross-hatch symbol on polygons in QGIS.

When displayed on screen, they look just fine - both in the map and in the composer.

The problem is when they are rendered to an image and/or printed, the hatching is much smaller in size (between the hatches) than on screen. The result is a much darker looking polygon that simply looks black, rather than a cross-hatch pattern that can be seen through to the colours below.

There is a print resolution setting (DPI) that when changed to 96dpi, it will render as it does on screen. But how to fix for 300dpi printed maps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the "New symbology" button (top right on the layer properties panel), then the "Change" button (middle left, under the preview) and then two angled "Line pattern fill".

Another solution : SVG Symbols, cf. [Is there a SVG symbol library for qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/is-there-a-svg-symbol-library-for-qgis)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define the pattern using 'map units,' which should maintain relative sizes between the pattern and feature. However, even then, the pattern may shift (via x/y) even if proportionally correct.