# SVG symbols in QGIS 2.18

Tags: svg, qgis-2.18

I've made some SVG symbols in Illustrator. Using them in QGIS 2.18 will give the elements in the SVG with no line, only a fill, on export to PDF automatically a line and fill.

SVG elements that have type in it, type also get on export to pdf a line and fill. Is this a bug or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If this is about Print Composer, will you check whether ticking/un-ticking  **Print as raster** at **Composition | Export settings** section make the output image different?

Comment: @Kazuhito, yes it's print composer, export as raster solved the problem above. On screen in Qgis it looks fine too, so is it a minor bug on export? Another thing came up and is solved by this: text on screen in Qgis disappears on export as  PDF but reappeared when export as raster PDF

Comment: Glad it worked out. I am newbie and not qualified to say a bug or not, but I feel it is working normal. (Just because QGIS sometimes recommends me to print as raster when I make a nicely rendered map... so I assume QGIS prefers raster for a high-quality prints.)

Comment: I'm a newbie too but I prefer vector for raster in print. Thanks for the help, i hope this workaround is useful to others too!

Comment: I second that :). As it seems the recent development in composer is so fast, could we expect something more and more in QGIS 3?

Comment: @Kazuhito Hi, i wanted to ask you that how you able to saved a symbol in Illustrator as svg and used it in qgis(as svg)? because I've already converted/saved as svg, when I imported it in qgis, it was empty, there is no symbol.

Comment: @Nadira I am afraid this is diverting from Daniel's question, but you can start with this post [How to create svg symbols that have modifiable fill color, stroke color and stroke width?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/how-to-create-svg-symbols-that-have-modifiable-fill-color-stroke-color-and-stro) as the answer may be able to solve your issue, too.