# How to color SVG symbols in QGIS 2.18.14?

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

Why can I color some SVG symbols, but not others?

At symbol # 1 I can change the color, but not the others.

In the XnView viewer, the symbols are shown differently.

[image]

What qualifies an SVG symbol to change the color?

Even editing it in Adobe Illustrator, I do not understand what's happening!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It come from how is made the SVG, if you open a svg file in a text editor (svg are juste text file) you will see that the one with modifiable color have a part with like this : fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000", those with fixed color lack the "param" and have hardcoded color.

You could check this answers to get a better explanation than mine and learn how to edit the svg file for modifiable color

[How to create svg symbols that have modifiable fill color, stroke color and stroke width?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/how-to-create-svg-symbols-that-have-modifiable-fill-color-stroke-color-and-stro)

Comment: Thank you for helping to find the way. After searching for some time, I found the following: in Illustrator I opened an SVG file that works on QGIS and pasted the contents of one I need, in this case a heart symbol. I saved with the new name (heart) and edited the SVG file in Notepad ++. Just had this part  _"<path <=> M15.91,8.84c-1 ..."_ . Replaces only _"<path"_ with this _"<path fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width)"_ In QGIS I was able to change the color. Great.