# SVG on GeoServer not working

Tags: geoserver, svg

I have several SVGs, the simplest of them is the following SVG:

```
<?xml version=‘1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<svg viewBox="-337 43 2223 1812"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M1508 43h-1528v1528h1528v-1528z" glyph-name="exclam" name= "foreground" fill="rgba(252,133,33,255)" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-1855)" unicode="!" />

</svg>
```

When I try to render then in GeoServer they all fail to draw and resort to the default marker instead of the orange square I'm expecting (for the simple example).
I get a ton of messages "InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from string to Interpolation  only", and every once in a while i get "creating defaultMark".

If I convert the SVGs to PNG it displays fine (and changing the rule format to image/png from image/svg)

My GeoServer version is 2.11.0

The SVGs display okay in Chrome.

Comment: You might want to try out 2.14.x, it has a newer version of Batik, the library GeoServer uses to read the SVG files.

Comment: Didn't realize they upgraded to the newer batik, will try that, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching all fill definitions from rgba(..) to the equivalent #fc... solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/how-to-create-svg-symbols-that-have-modifiable-fill-color-stroke-color-and-stro) helped me come up with the following change:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-337 43 2223 1812">
  <path d="M1508 43h-1528v1528h1528v-1528z" glyph-name="exclam" name="foreground" fill="param(fill) #ff7f2a" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-1855)" unicode="!"/>
</svg>
```

Which still displays a black rectangle by default but if I include it as

```
<OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="ian.svg?fill=#ff7f2a" />
```

does display an orange square. But simple mark with an orange fill would probably work the same but faster.

```
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#ff7f2a</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </Mark>
          <Size>6</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
```

Comment: i edited the question, i have complex icons and this is just one example, anyways, when i open the file in inkscape it doesn't have any color and when i save it it still doesn't work (saving as inkscape svg or plain svg)

Comment: then you need to edit your question to make this information clear.

Comment: Hmm ive tried your new suggestion but it didn't work either, do you know any way i could debug the issue? To try and figure out what is causing the problem?

Comment: are you using an old version of geoserver?

Comment: Yeah 2.11, I'm going to upgrade to 2.14, see if it helps (i hope it will, according to @Andrea Aime they upgraded the library that deals with svg, thank you for helo