# Changing colour of imported SVG icon in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, markers, color, svg, icon

I have imported my customised icon (which was obtained through the `.jpeg` image conversion) for point layers using an SVG file.

This works well except for the fact that the original colour was replaced by black.

Under the `"Symbology"` menu I cannot change the colour of the `"SVG marker"` (see picture below).

If I try to change it in the level above under `"Marker"` this does not change the colour of the icon. Any ideas or suggestions?

[image: Example]

Here is the code of my SVG (opened in Browser):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="260.000000pt" height="390.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 260.000000 390.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<g transform="translate(0.000000,390.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M1163 3850 c-217 -23 -457 -120 -639 -261 -129 -99 -270 -272 -346
    -424 -92 -183 -130 -349 -130 -565 -1 -351 118 -638 366 -886 180 -180 367
    -283 611 -339 l100 -22 0 -264 0 -264 -237 -3 -238 -2 0 -170 0 -170 238 -2
    237 -3 3 -237 2 -238 170 0 170 0 2 238 3 237 238 3 237 2 0 170 0 170 -237 2
    -238 3 0 264 0 264 100 22 c244 56 431 159 611 339 185 185 290 380 345 639
    31 144 31 362 -1 502 -58 259 -161 447 -344 631 -185 184 -394 297 -646 348
    -97 19 -273 27 -377 16z m362 -369 c263 -69 477 -246 595 -493 66 -138 84
    -220 83 -388 0 -175 -18 -255 -92 -405 -108 -220 -311 -392 -545 -464 -101
    -31 -96 -35 -96 73 l0 93 92 53 c241 137 374 295 386 460 9 124 -33 188 -138
    212 -41 9 -74 8 -181 -6 -186 -26 -252 -14 -312 54 -22 24 -33 29 -50 24 -60
    -19 -87 -124 -52 -199 26 -54 65 -83 132 -99 55 -12 69 -12 122 1 33 9 68 13
    76 9 25 -9 1 -43 -43 -61 -59 -25 -133 -9 -277 61 -117 56 -205 72 -302 55
    -78 -14 -112 -32 -149 -82 -43 -59 -56 -122 -43 -212 9 -62 18 -87 43 -120 53
    -70 170 -125 291 -136 l60 -6 3 -97 c3 -113 8 -109 -94 -77 -190 59 -373 192
    -484 354 -46 68 -107 203 -132 292 -31 112 -30 334 1 448 94 350 368 603 724
    671 98 19 279 11 382 -15z"/>
    <path d="M1363 3270 c-38 -15 -63 -121 -70 -292 -7 -167 4 -217 58 -263 94
    -78 187 18 227 235 22 117 24 165 6 209 -19 49 -53 75 -130 101 -64 22 -61 22
    -91 10z"/>
    <path d="M1140 3243 c-69 -24 -121 -63 -155 -117 -28 -46 -30 -56 -27 -130 3
    -97 26 -214 54 -273 20 -42 59 -73 91 -73 13 0 77 63 77 75 0 2 11 46 25 97
    34 123 56 300 45 358 -5 26 -17 52 -30 62 -26 21 -23 21 -80 1z"/>
    <path d="M1685 3140 c-28 -31 -76 -250 -77 -352 0 -67 37 -124 87 -134 48 -9
    60 4 109 106 34 72 40 97 44 167 4 79 3 85 -27 131 -37 58 -56 77 -93 91 -21
    8 -29 6 -43 -9z"/>
    <path d="M744 3008 c-61 -41 -76 -78 -68 -168 16 -177 106 -329 194 -329 44
    -1 52 13 63 102 9 70 7 110 -7 224 -10 76 -24 153 -32 171 -12 29 -17 32 -57
    32 -34 0 -57 -8 -93 -32z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: which software did you use to create the svg?

Comment: I downloaded a jpeg image and converted it online to svg. This worked fine for another icon (although to be fair, that one was black to start with). @Taras where can I find the code?

Comment: doing the second way, I extract the code above

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply do it directly in QGIS via `Layer Properties > Draw Effects > Effect Properties`.

Open your SVG `Layer Properties` and click `Draw Effects` and then open the Star symbol `Customize effects` [image: Customize_effects].

[image: SVG_Layer_Properties]

Then use `Colorise` as an `Effect type`

[image: Effect_properties]

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Documentation | 14.1.3.3. Other Settings | Draw effects](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#draw-effects)
- [Introducing QGIS live layer effects](https://nyalldawson.net/2015/04/introducing-qgis-live-layer-effects/)

Comment: This is indeed easier!

Comment: @Felix, if my or another suggestion (from J.R or Erik) solves your problem, please accept it as a valid answer.

Comment: All of them work, I chose this one because it is the easiest to me.

Comment: I am wondering which brightness I have to chose to get the exat color which I chose in the color picker for areas which were black in the SVG.

Comment: Have you tried `0`?

Answer (score 15):

You need to edit the SVG file and replace the

`fill="#000000" stroke="none"`

by something like

`fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"`

the "param(xxx)" part allow you to set the xxx parameter from the qgis interface, the #XXX part is the default color.

For a more detailled explanation see this answer [How to create svg symbols that have modifiable fill color, stroke color and stroke width?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/how-to-create-svg-symbols-that-have-modifiable-fill-color-stroke-color-and-stro)

Comment: This is the best answer, IMO, as it also enables changing styling of image objects in the map composer. I've been doing this for SVG images for a while now when I wanted to be able to style logos directly in the composer and this method doesn't require to dig into a couple dialogs to change the color.

Answer (score 3):

Using notepad++ (or any other decent text editor) simply change in this part

`<g transform="translate(0.000000,390.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">`

the code for "fill" to any desired color. E.g. `fill="rgb(0,255,0)"` for a green symbol.

Comment: great, I will download notepad++. However, as I have no clue with this, may I also ask how the code would be for a dark pink / purple colour?

Comment: Feel free to google for a website which gives you RGB-codes for any color you like. E.g. https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html