# Styling lines with centroids by two different fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, svg, geometry-generator

I have a line layer showing sectors of roads that I want to style by two different fields without duplicating the layer.

- `"Field 1"` is an integer ranging from 0-25 defining road usage (street, path, bikelane, etc.)
- `"Field 2"` is an integer ranging from 0-16 defining road signs that are valid within the sector

I want the line to be colored by `"field 1"` (I need to be able to manually define colors for each number) and I need a centroid with different SVG-graphics depending on `"field 2"`.

Is there a way to achieve that without manually adding rule-based options for all 25x16 possible outcomes?

I can now run the line color from `"field 1"` via Data driven override. I am still not able to do the same with SVG graphics.

I added a marker line with a single centroid SVG-marker. I cannot manage to insert the expressions to set different files for my conditions.

I've tried full `'paths\filename.svg'` with both `/` and `\` or only start in from `@project_folder`. This is the only way I don't get any parsing errors. I also tried using `file_path()` and `file_name()` which generate errors.

Comment: If you need specific symbols and colours, I suggest using `data driven override` on both. This should be easier to handle and change.

Comment: As far as I know, data driven override can only define a gradient for a range? I need several mono-colors, I'll clarify the question on what exactly I want to show

Comment: You can use `CASE WHEN` conditions as override. E.g. `case when "x" = 1 then 'red' when "x"=2 then 'blue' when "x"=3 then color_rgb(255,181,57) else 'black' end`. Same goes for symbols.

Comment: Or define a color ramp conatinaing exactly those 26 colors (0-25) you want.

Comment: Can you share the exact expression you used for the svg data driven override? Sometimes it helps to use a funciton like `right()` around your expression to extract, say, the last 30 characters and make sure you have a valid path. I regularly forget whether I should add a \ before the custom part of the path or not...

Comment: I tried (alsways betweeen `case....end`):

`when "Schild"=1 then '\\srv-daten\dokument\projectfolder\Projektdaten_Erhebung\Verkehrszeichen_Piktogramme\Zeichen_237_-_Sonderweg_Radfahrer_StVO_1992.svg'`

or

`when "Schild"=1 then file_path(\\srv-daten\dokument\projectfolder\Projektdaten_Erhebung\Verkehrszeichen_Piktogramme\) AND file_name(Zeichen_237_-_Sonderweg_Radfahrer_StVO_1992.svg`)`

and also the variantions I mentioned in edit1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the desired output

[image: result]

apply the following settings for

#### Colour

Use the following expression in the *Expression String Builder*

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "Field1" = 2 THEN '#264653'
    WHEN "Field1" = 9 THEN '#2A9D8F'
    WHEN "Field1" = 16 THEN '#E9C46A'
    WHEN "Field1" = 18 THEN '#F4A261'
    ELSE '#E76F51'
END
```

[image: colour]

#### Line centroid symbology

Firstly *Add symbol layer* and make an SVG-marker out of it. After trying the following expression in the *Expression String Builder* for *Dynamic SVG parameters*

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "Field2" = 1 THEN 'P://Test//qgis_test//socicon_amazon.svg'
    WHEN "Field2" = 3 THEN 'P://Test//qgis_test//socicon_apple.svg'
    WHEN "Field2" = 8 THEN 'P://Test//qgis_test//socicon_github.svg'
    WHEN "Field2" = 13 THEN 'P://Test//qgis_test//socicon_google+.svg'
    ELSE 'P://Test//qgis_test//socicon_mail.svg'
END
```

[image: centroid]

*Note:* Central point was used for Marker placement.

---

## Currently changing(overriding) simultaneously the colour and style of the SVG-file can not be done.

### An Attempt

With this approach, you can get control over your symbology, see the image below.

[image: attempt1]

Unfortunately, in this case, it is not possible to adjust the colour that easily. I was hoping to apply the method as was mentioned in [one of my previous solutions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305202/changing-colour-of-imported-svg-icon-in-qgis-3-4/305208#305208).

[image: result1]

### Working Solution #1

Using the Categorized symbology

[image: solution1]

### Working Solution #2

Using the Rule-based symbology

[image: solution2]

**Disadvantage:** In both approaches you will need manually to change the colour (⚠️ not dependent on the `"Field2"`)

I am on Windows 10 with QGIS 3.18.1-Zürich.

---

**References:**

- [Index of /account/themes/account/assets/global/plugins/socicon/svg](https://www.blogads.de/account/themes/account/assets/global/plugins/socicon/svg/)

Answer (score 2):

Cross-referencing to my [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415336/186820), I am now able to produce said symbology using a simple line and a marker line with centroids:

[image]

On my simple line I use *data driven override* (DDO) to style line color with `color_rbg(0,0,0)` to style by `"field1"` and also use a second DDO to make some lines dotted with values of `"field1"`.

On the added marker line I chose single centroids and changed type to SVG marker. There I again used DDO to style my centroids by `"field2"`. Normally, any of @Taras approaches on the other post should work, although I can only manage to use the reference to online sources via URL, now having to bear with long/endless loading times.