# Using QGIS variables within SVG graphics

Tags: qgis, print-composer, svg

If you use SVG symbols within QGIS you can use params like these so you can adjust properties interactively in QGIS:

```
fill = param(fill) 
fill-opacity = param(fill-opacity) 
stroke = param(outline) 
stroke-width = param(outline-width) 
stroke-opacity = param(outline-opacity)
```

I would like to do the same with text within an SVG-image:
Use (text-)placeholders in the SVG and fill in the actual text stored as QGIS variables within the print composer:

[image: example]

Is this already possible?

Comment: sorry to ask but ... how do u do that **for svg symbols** ? could u point to any ressource about that functionality ?

Comment: @snaileater: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/how-to-create-svg-symbols-that-have-modifiable-fill-color-stroke-color-and-stro  there is also something newer but only available in german language: http://geosysnet.de/custom/downloads/Vortrag_QGIS_Inkscape_FOSSGIS_2018_Hannemann.pdf

Comment: I think you can't do it for text directly in QGIS with QGIS tools, If you want change or handle text properties in svg images you can use web fonts and then begin changes on them by css and xml code in a text editor, I recommend refer to this lik:https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/how-do-i-use-a-custom-font-in-an-svg-image-on-my-site, I hope it would be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can display SVG with HTML like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

*source* : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

In a print composer, create a text label and check `Render as HTML`, you can place variables in placeholders :

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="[%@color%]" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Great Idea. I guess it's the only way to use qgis variables inside svg graphics at the moment.