# Using .BMP image as customizable polygon fill in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, xml

Normally in my office, I work with ArcMap. For making vegetation maps, I use one specific fill all the time (surface1.bmp). This fill needs to be a different colour in each polygon/feature. In this crisis-times I work from home, using QGIS instead. The desired fill is not available in QGIS, so I imported it in the symbology as an SGV. However, I want to be able to customize the colouring of this fill.

How is this possible?

I imported it using Raster Image Fill and import the .bmp. This did not work, so i converted to SGV using inkscape. It looks fine, but I still cannot change colours for each feature as one could do with any other pre-cooked QGIS symbol style.

See below for the .bmp picture.

[image]

I want to be able to make the black and white different colours in QGIS, without having to do this manual before uploading it in QGIS.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to change the color in QGIS just now although I could import the bmp just fine.  One workaround would be to create marker fill versions of any raster fill symbols which I did long ago for other reasons.  But you could create a different bmp/png/jpg for each color, import each and save symbol with the same tag to group them together.  Then you just select the symbol with the color you want as needed.

Comment: Read this on how to make SVG with color setting : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/how-to-create-svg-symbols-that-have-modifiable-fill-color-stroke-color-and-stro/77421#77421, note that this only work on vector SVG so you will need to vectorise your .bmp before saving as SVG

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly with a raster image, with some restrictions (only one color can be changed). First you have to convert the image to a 2-bit (black and white) image, for example a tif. I used Irfan View for that: open your image and save it as TIFF with the black and white option. Then you use the image like described by yourself as a raster fill. Now the tricky part starts with using the wonderful draw effects in QGIS, best see the animated gif here: https://files.wheregroup.com/index.php/s/JciSsaC7RaCXiii
This method only works for one color (the black one)...